# What's the use of PreferredSize widget after null safety?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Before null-safety I could do:

```dart
class FooBar extends PreferredSize {
  final String data;
  FooBar(this.data);

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(100);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DashingText(data); // My own implementation. 
  }
}
```

and use it like:

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: FooBar('My App bar'),
)
```

But with null safety I'm getting an error that I need to provide `child` to the super class. If I have to provide a `child` to the super class then what's the benefit of overriding the `build` method of the super class? Is `PreferredSize` not an obsolete class after the arrival of null safety?

Answer (score 2):

`PreferredSize` widget's constructor require 2 parameters which are `Widget child` and `Size preferredSize` by making a class that `extends` this widget you need to comply to its constructor. In [its documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html) `PreferredSize` is described like this:

> A widget with a preferred size.
>
> This widget does not impose any constraints on its child, and it
> doesn't affect the child's layout in any way. It just advertises a
> preferred size which can be used by the parent.
>
> Parents like Scaffold use PreferredSizeWidget to require that their
> children implement that interface. To give a preferred size to an
> arbitrary widget so that it can be used in a child property of that
> type, this widget, PreferredSize, can be used.
>
> Widgets like AppBar implement a PreferredSizeWidget, so that this
> PreferredSize widget is not necessary for them.

As said above your implementation should looks more like a `StatelessWidget` implementing a `PreferredSizeWidget` in the same way it is described for `AppBar`:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Hello, World!');
  }
  
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(100);
}
```

**Edit: Sample with PreferredSize**

```dart
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(80.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: <Color>[Colors.blue, Colors.pink],
            ),
          ),
          child: const AppBarContent(),
        ),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Content'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**AppBar implementation from Flutter source**

```dart
class AppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm already aware of `extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget` which `PreferredSize` also is, and sorry your post doesn't answer my question. Can you put an example of `PreferredSize`?

Comment: I've edited my answers with the code sample for `PreferredSize` which you can find in the Flutter documentation. What I meant with my answer was that you were using `PreferredSize` in the wrong way based on the code sample you have provided. You can find the base purpose of the widget `PreferredSize` described in its documentation and in my answer quotation.

Comment: If your purpose with your code sample was to create a custom appBar then you can wrap your custom widget with `PreferredSize` or implement `PreferredSizeWidget` on it. You were asking the purpose of using `PreferredSize`, well it is (quoting the documentation here): "Advertises a preferred size which can be used by the parent."

Comment: I think you didn't read the question carefully. My code was working fine until null safety but now it is not working (which I already know why). The question wasn't how to make it work or why there is an error but is `PreferredSize` widget obsolete now?

Comment: I've read your question but it wasn't really clear with the code you've added. Now is the `PreferredSize` widget annotated as `deprecated` or is it mentionned anywhere in its documentation that it is obsolete ? No. While you might not need to use it often, other developers might find use in this widget. Saying that it is obsolete would be the same as saying the `Padding` widget is obsolete because `Container` has a padding property. We cannot be sure how developers will use `PreferredSize` but maybe in some cases it might be more relevant than implementing `PreferredSizeWidget` for them.